# "another installation is already running"

Tags: error, installation

I am trying to install blender for the first time. I have tried the most recent three releases and all have same problem (for me). Which is an error message saying I already have an installation in progress.

I am on windows 10 and shut down my computer after use.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to solve the problem - not enough data.

But there is no reason to install Blender, just download and install zip archive in preferred directory!

You can use several versions:

[image: unzipped blender]

User folders used automatically:

[image: user files for different versions]

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, can you tell me where I should put extracted files? Can I put them on a USB drive?

Comment: Yes you could put Blender on USB, but data reading speed from USB will be worse then from HDD or especially SDD drive, program loading can be several times slower. Besides User folders will stay at the AppData User path therefore, it will not be a portable version, on another system (same as the other user) will be the factory settings..
I can recommend you to use path something like c:\apps\